# TeXnicCenter: opening PDF viewer internally

Tags: viewers, texniccenter

Is there a way to view the PDF file internally in TeXnicCenter?

Answer (score 4):

As stated on the [TeXnicCenter download page](http://www.texniccenter.org/download/), in order "to start working with LaTeX, you also need a TeX distribution and a PDF viewer."

TeXnicCenter does not provide an internal viewer. You need to set up the specifics as part of your PDF output profiles under the *Viewer* tab.

Comment: It may be an external program, but you can use Build->Define Output Profiles->Viewer to automatically execute it each time you build.